# Is there an Eclipse Plugin for showing file changes done real time?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

It is almost similar to a version control system, but in a version control system, the diff is shown between the state of the file when checked-out and the state of the file after checking-in. We don't have information about the modifications done during the intermediate session.
Its almost like the timeslider feature as part of etherpad. But this feature in eclipse IDE would help the developer be aware of the modifications done by him/her from the time he/she makes the first edit in the source file till the time he ends editing (when he saves the file by CTRL+S). It also tells that in this file, these are the modifications done from a starting timestamp to ending timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly a built-in functionality is close to what you search for: In a file's context menu select `Compare With > Local History...`. I don't know the timeslder feature (it sounds nice); here you get a list of versions and timestamps. Those are discret versions, so it is not "live" (as in every single letter or change).

A "live" view is possible with `Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Quick Diff` `Enable quick diff, Show differences in overview ruler`. Then the developer sees changes as colored blocks in the overview ruler to left in editor windows. You can even set the reference, either last saved local version or SCM base version. With the first the display is cleared on saving.

Comment: thanks his. Your answer is the closest to what I wanted to view in eclipse. But, a timeslider in addition to this would be more nice.